# Javascript String Output - Something to do with its type

Tags: javascript, string, byte

I have a variable - I know its a special byte array or something similar - i might be wrong.

The question is I am expecting to print this on console

```
\xddSM\x8f\xda0\x10\xfd+\xab\xd9kH\xe2\xb0\x85\x92S\x17zi\xb5\xaaV\xdam/\x15\x07\xe3\x0c\xc4\x95?\x90\xed\x04\xe8*\xff\xbdc\x03\xdbVZ\xb8\xf5R
```

but all i see is this

```
�SM��0�+��kHⰅ�Szi��V�m/�ĕ?���*��c�VZ��R
```

I cant post the code for it - But I guess some of you might have already got the idea

Comment: I think this is because characters are rendered as unicode characters, but some doens not exist. here for example, `\xdd` should print character 221 in unicode, but the browser cannot display it (not SM is well printed because not in the charater code)

Comment: Hi @vivianaranha - looks like you are printing characters .. presumably you'll need to use some sort of formatting to decode the "bytes" to human readable characters .. what have you tried?

Comment: I tried .toString('hex');

Comment: Is there a way to print as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the escape function like this to print the string to the console or insert it into the HTML.

```js
var x = escape("\xddSM\x8f\xda0\x10\xfd+\xab\xd9kH\xe2\xb0\x85\x92S\x17zi\xb5\xaaV\xdam/\x15\x07\xe3\x0c\xc4\x95?\x90\xed\x04\xe8*\xff\xbdc\x03\xdbVZ\xb8\xf5R").replace(/(%)/g, "\\x").toLowerCase();

document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```